# What is the first reference to a nondeterministic Turing machine?

Tags: computer-science

I am looking for the first reference of a Nondeterministic Turing machine. There is no mention of them in the 1936 paper ["On Computable Numbers."](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~robins/Turing_Paper_1936.pdf)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[According to SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/turing-machine/#VariTuriMach), non-determinism was introduced by [Rabin and Scott in Finite Automata and their Decision Problems (IBM Journal of Research and Development, 3(2) 114–125, 1959)](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~coquand/AUTOMATA/rs.pdf). Their main result was that it does not lead to a stronger notion of computability:

> "*The automata used throughout Chapter I were strictly
>   deterministic in their tape-reading action, which was
>   uniquely determined by the table of moves, since there
>   was one and only one way the machine would change its
>   state in any particular situation. Requiring all machines to
>   be of this form can lead to rather cumbersome details, in
>   view of the large number of internal states needed even
>   for some relatively elementary operations. In this section
>   we introduce the notion of a nondeterministic automaton
>   and show that any set of tapes defined by such a
>   machine could also be defined by an ordinary automaton.
>   The main advantage of these machines is the small
>   number of internal states that they require in many
>   cases and the ease in which specific machines can be described.*"